# HCL Nomad Web: HTTP Response content type unsupported

Tags: java, lotusscript, hcl-notes

I've a Notes database with java agent, that receives HTTP POST request and returns plain text in response.

A part of java agent code that initializes output, sets the content type and puts a string to the output.

```
    try {
        this.output = this.getAgentOutput();
        output.println("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        
        output.println("ABCDEFGH");
        
    } finally {
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    }
```

A part of client side LotusScript that sends POST request and reads the response:

```
Set webRequest = session.CreateHTTPRequest()
webRequest.preferstrings  = True
serverResponse = webRequest.post(serverUrl, jsonPayload)
```

This code works in HCL Notes client perfectly. But when I try to run the same LotusScript code from the HCL Nomad Web, I get error message:

`HTTP Response content type unsupported`

I don't understand what content type is suitable for HCL Nomad Web, if a simple text/plain is not supported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the NotesHTTPRequest class is not yet supported on Nomad Web.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any links to official documentation about that?

Comment: Just have got confirmation from HCL that it is true. Thank you.